# View isnt updated when a new variable that is added in mounted is changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list in utils that I use it almost everywhere and it only has `text` variable in each object.

In one of my components, I need to add `done` variable to each item in that list so I can toggle them. I can see that the variable is added, but whenever I toggle it, the view does not get updated.

```js
const arrayFromUtils = [{
    text: "Learn JavaScript"
  },
  {
    text: "Learn Vue"
  },
  {
    text: "Play around in JSFiddle"
  },
  {
    text: "Build something awesome"
  }
];

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: arrayFromUtils
  },
  mounted() {
    this.todos.forEach(item => (item.done = false));
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo) {
      todo.done = !todo.done

      console.log('toggled item: ', todo);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="todo in todos" :key="todo.text">
    <div @click="toggle(todo)" :class="{ red: todo.done }">
      {{ todo.text }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can see that `done` variable gets updated when toggling an item, but the view does not get updated. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a property to each of your todos items. To make it reactive, you need to use `this.$set`. Take a look at the documention about [changes detection caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects).

Your `mounted` function should be:

```js
mounted() {
  this.todos.forEach(item => this.$set(item, "done", false));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey it's problem with Vue Reactivity
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

You are changing item in array if you want to do this you need to use vm.$set or map whole array.

If you do this in your way vue can't detect if something changed that will be posible in vue3 :)

```
mounted() {
  this.todos.map(item => ({...item, done: false});
}
```